# AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in CommentsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a little problem, this code works:

```
def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  if verify_recaptcha
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  else
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end
end
```

Why this code does not work?:

```
def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  if verify_recaptcha
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  else
    render(
      html: "<script>alert('Recaptcha error!')</script>".html_safe,
      layout: 'application'
    )
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end
end
```

I get this error:

> AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in CommentsController#create
>   Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.

Please note that you may only call render or redirect, and at most once per action.

Also note that neither `redirect` nor `render` terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like `redirect_to(...) and return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't combine `render` with `redirect_to`. You're already rendering the `application.html.erb` file as layout, and the html is the `script` you assigned.

If you want to use `render` you have to know that this one doesn't run any code in the target action, so, if you want to "reassign" the `@article` variable you'll have to use `redirect_to`, and if you want to add some message to notify the user then you can add a `flash` message, which you can display then in your view:

```
...
else
  flash[:error] = 'Recaptcha error!'
  redirect_to @article
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<% if flash[:error] %>
  <div class="error">
    <%= flash[:error] %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: <% flash.each do |key, message| %>
  <p class="<%= key %>"><%= message %></p>
<% end %> It works fine, thanks!

Comment: I used `error` just to exemplify. You can add flash keys as you want.

Comment: But if - <div class="error"><%= error %></div> - I get this error: NameError in Articles#show
undefined local variable or method `error' for #<#<Class:0x007fe7e6762430>:0x007fe7e5025448>
Why?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try ***render_to_string*** instead of ***render***.

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html

Regards